# youtube data api in react native

Tags: react-native, google-api, youtube-data-api

How I can use youtube data api in react native or can load google api? 
Please someone help.

Comment: Hi Ahmed. Please provide proper explanation of your problem and question. Update your question with the code which is producing the error so that others can understand and help.

Comment: thank u suraj for reply, I just want to use youtube data api in react native plz let know if you know how